# Root cannot install packages in rescue or chroot plus service errors

Tags: arch-linux, permissions, hostname, logind, drm

I am using Arch linux.
Currently, I am having the trouble of:

```
User Login Management failed
User Login Management failed
User Login Management failed
User Login Management failed
Kernel Module drm failed
Hostname Service failed
```

error.

I tried rescue shell and chrooting, but even though I was able to login as user or root, I was not able to install any packages. I am getting permission denied error. Although, it is able to connect to repositories and see which packages need to be installed.

I do not know the cause of this, it happened after a restart.
When the computer starts, all I get is a black screen with a cursor. Cannot even change ttys, all I get is blinking underscore.

hostnamed.service error is:

```
Operation not permitted
Failed with result resources
```

logind.service error is the same.

One thing about hostnamed.service journal is at some point before, it states as

```
D-Bus name org.freedesktop.hostname1 now not owned by anyone.
```

I don't know what it means.

When I mask these 2 services, it doesn't show any errors, but I still get black screen with cursor, without being able to login.

I still do not have any idea why root is able to connect to repositories, but not able to have permissions to var/cache/pacman....

When I try, start sddm, I still get black screen with cursor.

How can I solve this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you try `su`?

Comment: I tried su - and su - user, same result.

Answer (score 0):

The root filesystem is usually mounted read-only in rescue mode.
Running the command below (the awk bit filters out information for only the root FS):

```
# mount | awk '$3 == "/"'
    
/dev/vda4 on / type xfs   
(rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,logbufs=8,logbsize=32k,noquota)
```

Should show (ro...) in your case if it is mounted in read-only mode.

Try

```
# mount -oremount,rw /
```

then the commands.